# How can I do a CASE statement within a distinct clause?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I'm trying to create a Hive view that has the following logic:

```
create view test.view as
select
distinct(
  case 
  when substr(value_1, 1, 10) < "2016-01-01" then
     regexp_extract(value_2,'(?i-sx:\\|([1-9][0-9]{0,3}x[1-9][0-9]{0,3})\\|)',1)
   else
     split(value_2, '\\|')[5]
   end
  ) as value_3
from test.table;
```

But when I run this, I get the following output:

```
FAILED: ParseException line 128:2 cannot recognize input near 'distinct' '(' 'case' in select expression
```

Does anyone know how I can write this so I don't get an error? Or tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Disregarding the error, would you mind adding a data sample?  I wonder what you are trying to do here

Answer (score 1):

`distinct` is not a function. It's applied on all the columns selected and produces unique combination of *all* the selected columns.

Try this:

```
select distinct case 
        when substr(value_1, 1, 10) < "2016-01-01"
            then regexp_extract(value_2, '(?i-sx:\\|([1-9][0-9]{0,3}x[1-9][0-9]{0,3})\\|)', 1)
        else split(value_2, '\\|') [5]
        end as value_3
from test.table;
```

So, this:

```
select distinct (col), col2
```

is same as:

```
select distinct col, col2
```

Comment: I actually don't know any provider that supports `select col, distinct col2`